# Garden wall pointing / capping advice needed

Tags: walls, brick, cement, retaining-wall, gardening

I’m hoping to get some advice on a project I’m planning.

I bought a house last year that has a 2 foot retaining wall between the decking and the lawn. It’s a red brick wall and looks to be in pretty bad shape.
Normal red brick used to cap the wall are all crumbling
Some whole sections appear to be quite loose
Could be leaking through from behind?
I haven’t done much of this kind of work before so I’d love to get some feedback on my plan to correct this to understand if I’m along the right lines.

I was planning to firstly rake back all the cement and repoint with another cement mix (maybe 4 to 1 mix). I was intending to do the whole wall so it matches.
Then I want to chisel off the current capping bricks and replace them with blue engineering bricks.

I’m hoping this might be enough but I’m worried it won’t address the underlying problem if there is water coming in from behind the wall, some of the marks down the wall look like it’s been leaking, if that’s the case I’m not really sure what to do. Maybe dig down behind the wall and see what’s going on?

Thank you for any comments / advice

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Water _will_ leak through the wall. You need to have weep holes above the bottom course of bricks to allow the water a place to freely run instead of having to force itself out everywhere. Using a masonry bit the size of your mortar joints, drill a series of holes (every 18" or so) through the joints. I'll leave the rest of the question up to others to address.

Comment: @FreeMan thank you. I hadn't come across that before but makes complete sense. I guess I assumed the draining needed to run along the inside face of the retaining wall running in the same direction as the wall. I'm planning to do some digging and see what's going on behind there.

Comment: I agree with freeman watch out for the electrical when digging and backfill with rock that would help drainage for that area.